# Continuous Delivery with TFS 2010 and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

Our development team uses Visual studio 2013 Pro along with TFS 2010. We need the following abilities for our continous integration / delivery initiative:

```
1. Automatically build our web project on every checkin.
2. Automatically deploy green builds to development and/or test environments.
3. Provide build/deployment notifications via email.
Extra Credit: Run unit tests with each build.
```

We don't have a budget, the reason Jenkins is appealing. The setup is new to me and not sure how the pieces fit and what other tools are needed to preform the tasks above?

Comment: You'd need to provide more details of what type of SCM and code you have, and how you deploy. But assuming Microsoft tools, Jenkins has plugins for TFS and VSTS to check out code, to build with MSBuild, run tests and publish results with the NUnit plugin, and to deploy by publishing artifacts over SSH, FTP, SMB etc., and then send emails.

Comment: I think you pretty much got our setup...right now we are strictly Microsoft tools. Just curious, if MSBuild (builds) and Web Deploy (automated builds) would still needed if we used Jenkins along with TFS 2010. Seems like the answer is Yes?

Comment: I don't know enough about newer MS build or deployment tools to say. I know that people use the MSBuild plugin to build their software with Jenkins. But if you use a different tool, so long as it can be run from the command line, then it can be run from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MSDN subscriptions, you can use TFS for free.  TFS 2015 can provide all these features.  TFS 2010 can provide most of this as well.

Use a gated checkin or CI build definition in TFS (2010 and 2015) to automatically build on checkin and run tests.  The build definition has the option to run tests as part of the build.

Use MSDeploy to package up your components into an automated package.  Most people don't know you can use it for more than web applications.  ([For example, databases](http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/))

TFS also provides email alerts on many events.

Regarding automating the deployments, we used separate TFS (in 2010) build definitions to trigger deployments to each environment.  Now we use TFS 2015 which supports [release definitions that adds many more options](http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/01/20/review-vsts-release-management-vnext/).

Comment: Just out of curiosity and not knowing..why is Jenkins and other CI/CD tools being pushed if TFS already offer these features?

Comment: The TFS 2015 features are still very new but catching up very quickly.  In general I think its ready for most companies.  Jenkins just has been around longer and is "free".  Regarding older versions of TFS, there just haven't been a lot of tutorial/examples of how to do it.  I am on a personal mission to change that.  There is no reason for shops with older legacy code to not use MSDeploy and TFS for CI/CD.

Comment: TFS build used to be terrible. The new build system introduced in TFS 2015 is significantly better. However it's still behind Jenkins and TeamCity for features and flexibility. As chief7 says it's catching up fast. If your stuck on TFS 2010 though then Jenkins is probably the best way to go IMHO

Comment: Quick question guys, if I go with TFS2010/Jenkins. Is MSBuild and Web deploy not needed?

Comment: Jenkins does CI and builds? Can be setup to do continuous build without another tool?

Comment: I have never used Jenkins personally but I believe you can use it to setup CI builds but you will still need MSBuild which there is a Jenkins plugin for.  Regarding deployments, I don't believe Jenkins provides any way to deploy natively.  They rely on plugins to provide that.  So you would need MSDeploy or some other deployment framework/tool.